# Protostuff runtime schema and polymorphism issues

Tags: java, serialization, polymorphism, deserialization, protostuff

I have a hierarchy of classes in Java that I want to serialize and deserialize using protostuff.

The classes are the following (just a toy example)

```
class Wrapper {
    public List<Being> beings;
}

class Being {
    public Animal animal;
}

class Animal {
    public String sex;
    public int legs;
}

class Antelope extends Animal {
    public int speed;
    public String furType;
}

class Spider extends Animal {
    public int numberOfEyes;
    public int size;
}
```

I'm using the following code to serialize and deserialize the objects using runtime schema generation as the following

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedBuffer buffer = LinkedBuffer.allocate(1024 * 1024);

    Being b1 = new Being();
    Antelope a1 = new Antelope();
    a1.legs = 4;
    a1.furType = "Fuzzy";
    a1.sex = "M";
    a1.speed = 70;
    b1.animal = a1;

    Being b2 = new Being();
    Spider s1 = new Spider();
    s1.legs = 4;
    s1.sex = "M";
    s1.numberOfEyes = 8;
    s1.size = 2;
    b2.animal = s1;

    Wrapper w = new Wrapper();
    w.beings = new ArrayList<>();
    w.beings.add(b1);
    w.beings.add(b2);

    // Serialize
    Schema<Wrapper> schema = RuntimeSchema.getSchema(Wrapper.class);
    byte[] data = ProtostuffIOUtil.toByteArray(w, schema, buffer);

    // Deserialize
    Wrapper w1 = schema.newMessage();
    ProtostuffIOUtil.mergeFrom(data, w1, schema);

    System.out.println(w1.beings.get(0).animal.getClass());
    System.out.println(w1.beings.get(1).animal.getClass());
}
```

The issue is that the output of this code is

```
class Animal
class Animal
```

instead of

```
class Antelope
class Spider
```

How can I preserve the information of the polymorphism during the serialization/deserialization?

I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to enable the system property as described in the related test:

https://github.com/protostuff/protostuff/blob/master/protostuff-runtime/src/test/java/io/protostuff/runtime/InheritanceTest.java

Comment: Thanks! This actually fixed the issue! Had to add the following system property: protostuff.runtime.morph_non_final_pojos=true